# Complex if expression in list comprehension python

Tags: python

I have this if expression inside a list comprehension:

```
[(i,j,k) for i in S for j in S for k in S 
 if ((i+j+k==0) and (i!=0) and (j!=0) and (k!=0))]
```

but it seems to evaluate not as and in between my conditions but as or. Why is that happening?

The problem is that when one of i,j and k is 0 the tuple is not added which is not what i want. I want to emit only when all of them are 0. I.e: i want 0,3,-3 to be included in the result.

Comment: Why don't you just break it out into 3 different lines as a starting point....? (Why are they all for whatever in `S` though....)?

Comment: If you wrote this code on multiple lines you'd have space to write some nice comments explaining what it does.  Right now it's very hard to work out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To omit `(i,j,k)` only when *all* of them are zero, use the condition `(i,j,k) != (0,0,0)`:

```
S = range(-3,3)
x = [(i,j,k)
     for i in S
     for j in S
     for k in S
     if ((i+j+k==0)
         and (i,j,k) != (0,0,0))]
print(x)
```

prints

```
[(-3, 1, 2), (-3, 2, 1), (-2, 0, 2), (-2, 1, 1), (-2, 2, 0), (-1, -1, 2), (-1, 0, 1), (-1, 1, 0), (-1, 2, -1), (0, -2, 2), (0, -1, 1), (0, 1, -1), (0, 2, -2), (1, -3, 2), (1, -2, 1), (1, -1, 0), (1, 0, -1), (1, 1, -2), (1, 2, -3), (2, -3, 1), (2, -2, 0), (2, -1, -1), (2, 0,
-2), (2, 1, -3)]
```

---

To understand what went wrong with the original condition, `(i!=0) and (j!=0) and (k!=0)`:

Consider what happens when `i=0` and `j=1`:

```
| i != 0 | j != 0 | (i!=0) and (j!=0) | (i,j) != (0,0) |
| False  | True   | False             | True           |
```

`(i!=0) and (j!=0)` is `False` since `False and True` is `False`.
In contrast, `(i,j) != (0,0)` is always `True` unless both `i` and `j` are zero.

Adding `(k!=0)` makes the example more complicated, but the idea is the same.

Comment: You could also use `not (i==j==k==0)`

Comment: @eyquem: The OP explained in a now-deleted comment that he wants all tuples `(i,j,k)` except when `(i,j,k) == (0,0,0)`. I've added his comment to the original post so the question is clearer.

Comment: Excuse me. I should have thought that there were more chances that the error was on the OP's side than on yours !

Answer (score 4):

If you still want a one-liner, then the following is actually readable:

```
[i for i in itertools.product(range(-3, 3), repeat=3) 
 if any(i) and sum(i) == 0]
```

Comment: @eyquem There was a comment from the OP on a now deleted answer: "*the problem is that when one of i,j and k is 0 the tuple is not added which is not what i want. I want to emit only when all of them are 0"*

Comment: I would write ``... if sum(i) and any(i)`` because there are more cases in which sum(i) equals zero than the unique case i==(0,0,0)

Comment: OK excuse me . I didn't see this part... or I had the mind in the moon. unutbu already explained this to me. I will delete this comment too in some minutes

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify this greatly using `itertools`...

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement as icwr

S = [t for t in icwr(range(-3,3),3) if t != (0,0,0)]

print S
```

This is much simpler... (if it is what you want to do!)

Comment: `is not` refers to identity, not equality: you want `!=` instead.  When I run this code, I get `(0,0,0)` in `S`, because the tuple you construct in the listcomp isn't the same one you get back from `icwr`.

Comment: @DSM aaah. I've always suspected that, but never checked it.